# how to get real value from sql by dataset

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = this.test_recvTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbwins_sdDataSet.test_recv);
        for (int x=0;x<5;x++)
       {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("test1","test"+x);
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[x].Value = i;
        }
```

this code gave me the count value. how to fix it.

[image]

this is my dataset

[image]

this is my design view

[image]

this is value I want to show on my datagridview.

thank for help.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your below query result is present in dataset `this.dbwins_sdDataSet`;

```
SELECT SUM(CrAmnt - DrAmnt) as Summ
FROM mydb
```

just bind that dataset to your gridview which should get you the data in gridview you are looking for like

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = this.dbwins_sdDataSet;
```